# Why is git showing separate commits when I push things from the machine using terminal on Mac?

Tags: git, github

https://github.com/VideoSpike/nativescript-web-image-cache/commits/master

I am the same guy -- Sumeet Batheja and bathejasumeet

when I did
 `git push origin master`
 for the first time while updating the repo, it asked for creds, I provided the creds for bathejasumeet on the mac terminal, but it shows that Sumeet Batheja and bathejasumeet are different entities on the above commit page, is there a way to reconcile both of them?

Comment: Perhaps `git config user.email` on your Mac is set to an email address that's not linked to your GitHub account?

Comment: okay -- how do I change the existing commits that it shows from Sumeet Batheja to bathejasumeet?

Comment: @basum `git filter-branch --env-filter 'if test "$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME" = "Sumeet Batheja";then GIT_AUTHOR_NAME = "bathejasumeet";export GIT_AUTHOR;fi"` If you want to update the email, do the same to GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL. This rewrites the history. If the branch has been published, better not do `git filter-branch`.

Comment: @ElpieKay getting error GIT_AUTHOR_NAME command not found

Comment: @basum sorry. it should be `GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="bathejasumeet"`, with no space around `=`.